# I made mistake sending Bitcoin to old generated address in nairaex ...the transaction still writing unspent...how can I get my Bitcoin back

Tags: confirmations, confidential-transactions, confirmation-time-estimation

I got 22 confirmation for Bitcoin not up 50$  and still unspent ,ow can I get it reverse back ,it more than 4hours

Comment: Given Nairaex is a centralized exchange, it is highly unlikely that you would have the private key associated with the address. Your best hope is to contact the customer service of the exchange and ask them nicely if they would be able to help you. That is your only way out.

Answer (score 1):

> **I got 22 confirmation for Bitcoin**

22 confirmations of a Bitcoin transaction mean that transaction is certainly beyond any economic hope of alteration or invalidation.

> **not up 50$**

I don't know what you mean by this but will assume you mean the transaction was for an amount that is currently equivalent to USD 50. That makes it too small to be worth much effort to recover, you wouldn't spend 1000 USD to recover USD 50.

> **still unspent**

Someone knows the private keys associated with the receiving address. That person can create a new transaction sending the money back you - less Bitcoin transaction fees etc.

> **[h]ow can I get it reverse back**

You can't reverse a Bitcoin transaction.

Under some circumstances you can invalidate an unconfirmed transaction if you act quickly enough and are sufficiently knowledgeable. In your case it is too late.

> **old generated address in nairaex**

Since [NairaEx](https://nairaex.com/) is a Bitcoin exchange in Nigeria, you should ask them for help. It seems likely that they control the private keys associated with that address and are therefore the only people who can assist.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean the transaction is still unconfirmed? In that case there are two options.

1) If the original transaction was replaceable (depending on your wallet this is something you can set with a checkbox) you can use RBF (Replace By Fee).

2) If you cannot use RBF, you can try to double spend the original output(s) with a significant higher fee to convince miners to mine the 2nd transaction before the 1st, making the 1st transaction invalid.

If your transaction is already confirmed, than you will need the secret key of the old generated address to create a new transaction from the old address to the new address.

Comment: The questioner already mentioned that his transaction has 22 confirmations.

Comment: @UgamKamat I wasn't sure whether he meant his transaction got 22 confirmations or whether there were 22 blocks mined since he broadcasted his transaction, but I guess you're right.